# User authentication from multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have a login screen that can authenticate "users" on my web app. But i also want to reuse the same login for "customers". Its an e-commerce type of web application. I am using PHP and MYSQL mainly to do my login authentication using one table.Below is my current code for verifying "users":

```
//Query statement for selecting details from database
$Sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '".$user_name."' AND password = '".$password."'";
```

Comment: Why not join those two tables with common key and proceed as you are doing

Comment: Have a `type` column which is an enum, int, or varchar and set the type in that. This way you can differentiate the user type and have it all in one table. Generally, you have a users table which has the core information of the user (id, type, username, password, created, updated) and then you store "other" information (name, dob [...]) in another table link them via the user ID. ***However, as it currently stands, your question is too broad / primarily opinion based***.

Comment: Hey Rahul and Script47... Kindly note my edits. Hope the question is clearer now... Please advise

Comment: bro, your question is incomplete. you need to provide more details like you are using 2 different tables to store customers and users? and also if you are using the same table to store customers and users then there must be any column through which you are differentiating them. If you are not having one you can create a column like USER_TYPE  where you can define it is a user or customer or admin anything. after login, you can put a condition on the basis of user_type. You can also put condition at the time on inserting data into user when you create a new user.

Comment: @SayedMohdAli i am planning to use to tables to login. I want two kinds of people to use my web app, admins who manage the system and customers who want to view their profiles

Comment: you can create two tables and put customer data separately when created a new customer. and in the user table, you can only insert data like id, password and user type.
then you can use join between user table and customers table to get the customer details. during login. customer_id should be safe as same as user_id. so, that you can use join

Comment: **Never store plain text passwords!** Please use ***PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html)*** to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).  ***It is not necessary to [escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Answer (score -1):

Leaving coding part on your just demonstrating login in short. create column user_type in the users table.

Method 1: -

```
$Sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '".$user_name."' AND password = '".$password."'";


if($sql['user_type']=="customer"){

$sql2 = "select * from customers";
}
```

now use session to store customer fields.

You can also redirect to different pages

```
if( $user == 1){ //check if user or password is correct from query


 if($user_type == "customer"){ //check usertype

    header("Location:/application/app.php"); //if normal user redirect to app.php

    }else{

    header("Location:/administration/admin.php"); //if admin user redirect to admin.php

    }
}
```

[[follow this link for tutorials : link1][1](http://www.techyari.in/2014/10/multi-user-role-based-login-in-php-with-mysql.html)](http://www.techyari.in/2014/10/multi-user-role-based-login-in-php-with-mysql.html)

[[follow this link for tutorials : link2][2](http://codewithawa.com/posts/admin-and-user-login-in-php-and-mysql-database)](http://codewithawa.com/posts/admin-and-user-login-in-php-and-mysql-database)

Comment: Let's not teach/propagate sloppy and dangerous coding practices. If you post an answer without prepared statements [you may want to consider this before posting](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/344703/). Additionally [a more valuable answer comes from showing the OP the right method](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290789/1011527).

Comment: you mean, if someone is using PHP 5.6 and his whole project is an old version of PHP. I will first tell them please update your whole project for PDO or MYSQLI and then I will answer them? I should not answer according to their question and queries but I have to tell them please update to newer version of PHP? I should not solve their problem but need to create a new problem for them. I should not go for the logic they are asking me I should go for their mistakes?

Comment: No, you must demonstrate (or warn) the user against SQL injection. Version 5.6 allows PDO and MySQLi prepared statements, so this isn't about versions. BTW, that is not my downvote

Comment: @JayBlanchard I am sorry, I have't warn them for the version issues but it not something related to their question. I do not want to go OFF topic, you can warn them instead.

Comment: I did warn them in comments. A ***good answer*** will have similar warnings, not only for the OP but for future visitors to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Good work, I gave positive voting for that because your comment was helpful for his project and organization but it not related and he is not asking for that, he is asking for the simple logic.

Comment: SMH. The security and safety of the code is *totally* related. If you don't do it correctly from the beginning when will you find the time to go back and fix it?

Comment: yes, but is not something he asked for that is why I have not included that part in my answer but you mentioned it in a comment that was enough, I gave you a positive rating for that but it, not something I have to answer. There is a lot of people who still use MySQL in their project instead of PDO and MySQLi and you will find them all over stackoverflow